# Leaflet Transform draw Marker from data Ionic 2

Tags: leaflet, json

I want to draw markers from data on Leaflet map

I'm currently doing with that way

```
                 L.marker(
            [48.840346,2.319415]).addTo(map).bindPopup("<b>X<b>"<img style='width: 100%' src='http://i.imgur.com/XMVjS1s.jpg'/></div> ",{minWitdh:256} ");
```

But i have a Data.json

```
  {
      "title": "A",
      "lat": 48.841491,
      "long": 2.355989,

   },
    {
      "title": "B",
      "lat": 48.878849,
      "long": 2.312855,
      },
```

i want to do something like this

```
 L.marker(
        [lat,long]).addTo(map).bindPopup("<b>title<b>"<img style='width: 100%' src='http://i.imgur.com/XMVjS1s.jpg'/></div> ",{minWitdh:256} ");
```

To get all The Data and render it on my Map ?

Answer (score 1):

This post should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506989/leaflet-popup-with-additional-information-from-geojson

You should use the "onEachFeature" to attach a popup to your marker and show the information stored in your json data. Then, access the properties of your json data through `feature.properties.*` in the bindPopup() function.

```
var myLayer = L.geoJson(myJson, {
    onEachFeature: yourOnEachFeatureFunction
}).addTo(map);

function yourOnEachFeatureFunction(feature, layer){
    if (feature.properties.title) {
        layer.bindPopup("<b>" + feature.properties.title + "<b><img style='width: 100%' src='http://i.imgur.com/XMVjS1s.jpg'/></div>");
    }
}
```

The `if` condition is to be sure that you have a `title` property in your json data.

BTW, you could also store the src of the image in the json data.

To load the json in your leaflet map instead of hard-coding marker coordinates (`L.geoJson(myJson,...)`), I suggest to have a look at the leafllet documentation or in this forum. The way I usually do is to use jquery and its function $.getJSON():

```
var myGeojson = []; // global variable       

$.getJSON("./geojson/mygeojsonfile.json", function(data) {
          $.each(data.features, function(i, f) {
               myGeojson.push(f);         
         });

         var myLayer = L.geoJson(myGeojson, {
             onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindPopup("<b>" + feature.properties.title + "<b><img style='width: 100%' src='http://i.imgur.com/XMVjS1s.jpg'/></div>");
             }
           }).addTo(map);
        });
```

J.